# Implement JWT token based REST API with Spring boot and Integrate Spring Social

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, jwt, spring-social

This question may look like work flow requirement but I would like to get advice about both workflow as well as implementation part of JWT based REST service in spring Boot with spring social APIs integrated with it. 
I have a working code base, which works fine with custom JWT token implementation. I find it difficult to integrate spring social APIs along with it. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And your question is...?  Also: look here: [Spring Security - OAuth/OAuth2](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/) and here [Stateless authentication with Spring and JJWT](http://technicalrex.com/2015/02/20/stateless-authentication-with-spring-security-and-jwt/)